# Include NodeJs into Ionic

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ionic-framework

I built a hybrid application with Ionic.
Currently I am using PHP and MySQL as the backend.
As I informed myself this is pretty old style and the new ways are NodeJS with expressJS and MongoDB.
Unfortunately there are thousands of tutorials on how to build a MEAN app(MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS and NodeJs).
This doesn't help me a lot because I don't know how to integrate NodeJS into my existing Ionic app.
Can I only hook them up by changing the POST requests to my new NodeJS server instead of those to the PHP scripts?

I saw some cool ways where the routing of NodeJS was directly hooked up with the app.
How is that possible?

Like if I am navigating to www.testapp.com/test for example

```
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Hello World!')
})
```

I want to call this for example.
How is this possible in combination with Ionic?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I believe you can perform that, just calling as a rest api. So you can keep an nodeJS instance running as backend and the ionic can access that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you can use [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) (fast, unopinionated, minimalist web framework for Node.js).

1.) Install Express

```
$ npm install express --save
```

2.) Create simple API. Put this in **server.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

If you use MySQL (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) then use this

```
    var express = require('express')
    var mysql    = require('mysql')
    var app = express()

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('Hello World!')
    })


       var pool = mysql.createPool({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: '',
            password: '',
            database: ''
        }); 

        app.listen(3000, function () {
            console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
        })

  app.get('/partners', function(req, res,next){

  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

        if (err) {
            console.error("An error occurred: " + err);
        }

       var query = "SELECT * FROM partners ORDER BY idpartner DESC";

        var table = ["tableName"];

        query = mysql.format(query,table);

        connection.query(query,function(err,rows){

            if (err) {               
               return next(err);
            } else {
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    partners : rows
                });
            }
            connection.release();
        });
    });
});
```

3.) Run API with CMD or Git Bash.

```
$ node server.js
```

4.) Test API directly in  web browser or [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) (Supercharge your API workflow. Build, test, and document your APIs faster.).

Visit `http://localhost:3000/test` or `http://localhost:3000/partners`

5.) Use API **in Ionic** app

```
 $scope.getPartners = function() {
        $http.get("http://localhost:3000/partners", { params: { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" } })
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.firstname = response.firstname;
                $scope.lastname = response.lastname;
            })
            .error(function(response) {
                alert("ERROR");
            });
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much for the very detailed answer. I have just one question left about it. How can I hook up the app with the NodeJS server, so that let's say if the user is nagivgating to /partners, the server will automatically execute the appropiate funcion... Do you know what I mean? Do I have to execute the app on the same port as the server is running on in order to hook them up?

Comment: @Anokrize Each URL like this `http://localhost:3000/partners` is one API which can be used anywhere from website to hybrid mobile app. API to be used in the production need to be on web server (`pm2 start server.js`) for example `http://192.168.0.111:3000/partners` and then it is available to everyone. Server and applications are totally separate and the only way they will be connected it through GET, PUT, POST, DELETE requests from Ionic controllers. Server while running will constantly listen to your app requests through `$http.get`, `$http.put`, `$http.post`, `$http.delete`.